# What to do if we have multiple categorical columns multi class?

Tags: python, deep-learning, dataset, one-hot-encoding, dummy-variable

If dataset have multiple categorical values then do we need to perform OneHotEncoding on all of the categorical data, and then how to remove problem of dummy variable.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for. Yes, you can one-hot encode all of your categorical variables, what is the _problem of dummy variable_?

Comment: please see stackoverflow's guideline for asking a proper question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It it not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. Typically in machine learning you could do one-hot encoding or label encoding, but you need to encode categorical values before passing it to modeling.

IMO, Label encoding is simpler and can help in classical regressions/classifications and Onehot encoding can be used when you are planning to apply deeplearning. More discussion at : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/when-to-use-one-hot-encoding-vs-labelencoder-vs-dictvectorizor

Having said that you could do label encoding like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
numeric_cols = model_data_df._get_numeric_data().columns
for col in list(set(model_data_df.columns) - set(numeric_cols)):
        model_data_df[col] = le.fit_transform(model_data_df[col].astype(str))
```